# Why can't I add route in TwinCAT 3 between two PC with TwinCAT3?

Tags: plc, twincat, twincat-ads

Entered the credentials of the current/other windows accounts. I tried all sorts of combinations. Computers discover each other through broadcast search, but are not added to the static route.
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfjF3.png)

Comment: Hi Efim, welcome to StackOverflow. Tip: you can put a `!` in front of the `[]` of image links to show the actual images in the post. See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

After the broadcast search, click on the "Add Route", and then you will have to use the user name of the Target PC and its password for user credentials. Apart from this, you will also have to uncheck the Secure ADS option on the top left of the window. I hope this will solve your problem. The target system must be in config or run mode before connecting. A successful connection is shown by a "*" in the connected column of the window.

Comment: Thank you for answer. With unchecked Secure ADS option get error(see Picture). With checked option not get error, but not add route.

Comment: Have you done the TCP and UDP settings for the Runtime PC (Target System). Check here "https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcremoteaccess/html/tcremoteaccess_firewall.html&id="

Answer (score 1):

**Adding a user to the Administrators group**, and to enter the user name in the form of HOSTNAME\USERNAME helped me.

Comment: This was my solution after 2 hours of adding the target to have nothing show up